# Image hide and show not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zooming

I am using this [jquery.smoothZoom.min.js](http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142)  to zoom and pan image.I have successfully applied that to my project for single image,now i want to add (<,>.i.e. corousal) ,so that I can use it for multiple images.When I add the corresponding  part in my custom.js it does not work properly.

I will attach two screen sorts which will clear the picture

This is the first case
[image]

and after clicking the right corousal button

[image]

I can see only the background but not the required image . I can not understand what i am missing ,

This the html part i have been using

```
    <div class="image-display" id="displayplan4" style="width:70%;height:120%; left:39%;top:10%;position:absolute;display:none;"> 

        <img src="images/amenities.jpg" style="width:150%;height:130%; left:-60%;top:-20%;position:absolute;overflow:auto; z-index:1;">
        <div style="width:150%;height:130%; left:-60%;top:-20%;position:absolute;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);z-index:2;">
        </div>

        <img class="planzoom" src="gallery/Residential/ongoing/Almog/Plan/almog1.jpg" id = "almogplan0" style="width:100%;height:100%; right:3%;top:50%;position:absolute;z-index:3;">
                    <!--button for forward and backward movement-->
            <a href="#" > <img src="innerimages/forward.gif" id="almogforward" style="position:absolute;height:3%;width:2%;z-index:3;top:25%;right:20%;"></a>
            <a href="#" ><img src="innerimages/back.gif"     id="almogback"    style="position:absolute;height:3%;width:2%;z-index:3;top:25%;left:0%;"></a>
    </div>
```

and

```
<div id = "almogplandivII">
            <img class="planzoom" src="gallery/Residential/ongoing/Almog/Plan/almog2.jpg" id= "almogplan1" style="width:100%;height:100%; right:3%;top:50%;position:absolute;z-index:3;display:none;">      
        </div>
```

and the corresponding js part to show and hide image on mouse click upon the image.

```
var almog_plan_div=0;

//Function for image forward with forward button
$("#almogforward").click(function () 
{
    if(almog_plan_div<1)
    {
        $("#almogplan"+almog_plan_div).hide();
        almog_plan_div++;
        $("#almogplan"+almog_plan_div).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#almogplan"+almog_plan_div).hide();
        almog_plan_div=0;
        $("#almogplan"+almog_plan_div).show();
    }
}); 

//Function for image backward with backward button
$("#almogback").click(function () 
{ 
    if(almog_plan_div>0)
    {
        $("#almogplan"+almog_plan_div).hide();
        almog_plan_div--;
        $("#almogplan"+almog_plan_div).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#almogplan"+almog_plan_div).hide();
        almog_plan_div=1;
        $("#almogplan"+almog_plan_div).show();
    }
});
```

I have tried like adding `display:none` style properties but it does not help my cause,
any help on this ?

Comment: Do you have a live demo?

Comment: u mean something like jsfiddle ,
I tried it dint succeeded in creating that

Comment: yes or a live website preview

Comment: are you trying to run multiple smooth instance on the same page?

Comment: yes,am trying to do that ,is it not applicable?by the way i kept the website link for 1 hour after that i deleted,did u checked that ?

Comment: Yes I checked, that's why I asked above question. You can do that, but to do that you need to call multiple instance. I can see you are calling through $('.planzoom').smoothZoom, to differentiate you can use IDs instead and call them separately, multiple times.

Comment: u mean to say if i am going to use with a different id and use the same code it should work for me ,should there be no conflict any way i will try

Comment: its not working ,by the way i just used another instance for the single image

Answer (score 0):

Remove inline styling display: none from the img tag and then when u initialize your page, then hide that image using hide() function.

Inline-styling might be overriding this

Comment: Ishita am too raw to understand your solution can u plz pinpoint

Comment: You have this code: <div id = "almogplandivII">
            <img class="planzoom" src="gallery/Residential/ongoing/Almog/Plan/almog2.jpg" id= "almogplan1" style="width:100%;height:100%; right:3%;top:50%;position:absolute;z-index:3;display:none;">      
        </div> ... Now, remove display:none from this tag and when your page loads or wherever whichever first function gets called to display your page, write this line $("#almogplan1").hide();

Comment: @ ishita tried your solution ,its not working may be u r asking me to hide $("#almogplanII").hide(); I tried this also $("#almogplan1").hide();  ,but anyway it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of your answers ,both of u may not be exactly correct but definitely helped me getting me my solution.

The trick i was missing:

I) have used two different divs ,but i have not positioned the second one, (I noticed only that when I tried the whole thing in a new web page with only 2 images in it ,they were not positioned properly )my requirement needs the divs to be hidden ,i had to hide them.

2) The other thing i had to remove was the `position:absolute` thing from individual image elements.
Once rectified its cool now.